# Why Capybara feature tests don't wait?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I have a small trouble with my tests suite: when I run spec which the checking ajax action on the page, sometimes I get random error

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content 'DHH'
```

This error shows very rarely (about 1/100), but this very confused me. I decided this a 'race condition' cause, and I add this config in my `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
```

but this is don't help for me, and I decided add timestamps

```
  it 'adds new DHH', js: true do
    find('#modal_new_dhh').click
    fill_in('name', with: 'DHH')

    p 'click button'
    p Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
    click_button('Submit')

    p 'checking content'
    p Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
    expect(page).to have_content 'DHH'

    p 'after checking content'
    p Time.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%L')
  end
```

and see that

```
"click button"
"17:34:43.083"
"before checking content"
"17:34:43.127"
"after checking content"
"17:34:43.213"
```

why Capybara don't wait after click button?

sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wait in your example occurs in the have_content matcher.  Where you're outputting times from will never show a delay because click_button has nothing to wait for, it just clicks a button and moves on (because it has no idea what it would wait for, clicking a button could do anything), however the have_content matcher will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time for the content to appear.

Note your `find`, 'fill_in' and `click_button` calls also wait for the relevant elements to appear BEFORE performing their actions

Comment: Hi Tom! Btw, I have read now issue on github where you marked https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1481 :)

You say now that `have_content` matcher should wait to Capybara.default_max_wait_time, but it is not work for me. I updated the question

Comment: @vear Great, the important thing to realize is that Capybara can only wait for things it knows to wait for.  When you tell it to click a button it knows to wait for the button to appear before clicking it (so it's clickable), but has no idea what the result of clicking that button is, so would have no idea what to wait for after.

Comment: @vear What makes you think it's not waiting? It waits UP TO Capybara.deafult_max_wait_time but will return quicker when the page has "DHH" on it - so either your app has returned the updated page or you're checking for content that is already on the initial page (make sure you're checking for content that only appears on the page after whatever action clicking the button performs has finished)

Comment: @vear Yes, I understanding now

Answer (score 0):

As you said this is a race condition. As to why it happens, I can't really say, the only reason I could think of would be that there is a difference between a user experience and an automated testing, because computers are very fast.

I had faces the same challenge sometime ago and I found [this tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) which showed me a way to go about resolving these kind of issues. I hope it would be useful to you too.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I used It before, but I want to know - why capybara dont wait after click button

Comment: @vear Because clicking a button could do anything (or nothing) so there is no way to know what to wait for - Capybara waits when you tell it to find something.